# Gateway Timeout 504 after Clearing Cache

Tags: error, magento2.3.2, timeout

My new Magento 2 installation is stuck in a 504 Gateway Timeout state.

I removed the Cache folders via FTP
The Cache files have been recreated up to the letter F
There is 23Gb space available

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Kevin

Comment: Getting issue  during installing?

Comment: Not installing - the site has been working fine for weeks. Now it doesn't!

Comment: Its a server issue.

Comment: There are two sites on the server. The other is working fine - what could specifically after one site?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Although there was 23Gb of space, there was not enough allocated to that domain.